# How do I add thickness and add a material to hair particle mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, game-engine, hair

I've converted my hair particles to mesh because I want to use them in a game engine. I currently have two problems.

1. I don't know how to change the thickness of the hair (I've tried a solidify modifier)
2. I can't assign a material to the mesh.

Here is a photo reference:[image]

Thanks
Liam

Answer (score 0):

select particles and go to materials properties. You can hide the surface with particles and use a duplicate for see the bald.